# Nagios nrpe check_nrpe plugin missing

Tags: nagios, nrpe, ubuntu-14.04

installed nagios nrpe into remote machine from ubuntu repository

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-nrpe-server
```

and plugins as

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-plugins-basic nagios-plugins nagios-plugins-extra
```

but in /usr/lib/nagios/plugins location check_nrpe is missing.

How to get that plugin into this location. And i m really new to this nagios

Comment: What distro are you running?  Version?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

Comment: why i can't able to post questions in server fault ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you: you **have** posted a question in Server Fault, so your ability to do so ought not to be in question.

Comment: ok .. do u have the solution for my issue

Comment: Sorry, no; I'm very much a CentOS/RedHat man.  Hopefully someone who knows the ins and outs of NAGIOS on ubuntu will be along shortly.

Comment: ok .. pls remove the minus marks man .. i can't able to ask further more questions

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15492/discussion-between-sivashanmugam-and-madhatter).

Answer (score 4):

At least on Debian (may be the same for Ubuntu) you need the `nagios-nrpe-plugin` package. Install that, too.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. when i am tried to install nagios-nrpe-plugin there are some other services like apache,php,mysql and nagios3 also starts installing

Comment: how to aviod that .. pls guide me

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 16.04 (nagios-nrpe-plugin)